# Loops and functions:Retirment lab for class

Tags: c, loops

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.There are two issues which is the year won't go from 0 1 2 etc it goes 1 1 or 0 0, Also there is a second issue the interest won't add up like I intended. I have no clue what is wrong with it so I would love a second pair of eyes on it so ahead of time thank you.
Here is the source code and a portion of my output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET_VALUE 2000000
#define RATE .10




int main(void) 
{

int year;
double balance, target, finalbalance, deposit, rate, interest;

printf("Enter starting balance ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &balance);
printf("Enter amount deposited every year ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &deposit);
printf("Enter estimated annual interest rate (\%%): ");
scanf("%lf", &rate);
printf("Enter target balance ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &target);

year = 0;
interest = 0;

finalbalance = balance + deposit + interest;

printf("\nYear    Deposit    Interest    Balance");
printf("\n----    -------    --------    -------");
printf("\n%d   %.2lf    %.2lf    %.2lf", year, deposit, interest,
      finalbalance);
do {
    finalbalance = finalbalance + deposit + interest;
    printf("\n%d    %.2lf    %.2lf    %.2lf", year, deposit, interest,
    finalbalance);
    year += 1;
    interest = (finalbalance + deposit) * RATE;
} while (finalbalance <= target);

printf("\nIn year %d, balance %.2lf reaches target %.2lf", year, balance, target);
}



Enter starting balance ($):250000
Enter amount deposited every year($):20000
Enter estimated annual interest rate(%):10
Enter target balance ($): 2000000

year    deposit    interest    balance
0       20000.0     0.00        270000.00
0       20000.0     0.00        290000.00
1       20000.0     31000.00    341000.00
2       20000.0      36100.00    397100.00
```

This was the intended output that my teacher had given but my code does not 
match.

```
Enter starting balance ($): 250000.0
Enter amount deposited every year ($): 20000.0
Enter estimated annual interest rate (%): 10.0
Enter target balance ($): 2000000.0
 Year Deposit Interest Balance
 ---- ------- -------- -------
 0 250000.00 0.00 250000.00
 1 20000.00 27000.00 297000.00
 2 20000.00 31700.00 348700.00
 3 20000.00 36870.00 405570.00
 4 20000.00 42557.00 468127.00
 . . .
 . . .
In year ??, balance ????? reaches target 2000000.00
```

Comment: Nothing wrong it seems.. what's the issue in the code ?

Comment: The code works in its self but the issue is I have no clue how to get the year correct way or why the interest compiles the wrong way. so for example the year goes 1 1 2 and the interest adds 0 for those two 0 years and the compiles 31000 instead of going 0 then 27000 and then 31700.I'm sorry It's just i have no idea what is the issue with it.

Comment: See my answer , just uncomment hard coded values (Commenting scanf inputs) and run it.. Also I provided a working code link where you can see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch around some of what's going on in the loop. Increment year before printing. Those macros are unnecessary and your version was ignoring the input interest rate. It's typically preferable to put `\n` newlines at the end of `printf()` format strings. Divide the input interest rate by 100. `balance` and `finalbalance` were redundant. In year 0 the deposit is the initial balance. Most importantly, you can make everything pretty by specifying widths to `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

    int year;
    double balance, target, deposit, rate, interest;

    printf("Enter starting balance ($): ");
    scanf("%lf", &balance);
    printf("Enter amount deposited every year ($): ");
    scanf("%lf", &deposit);
    printf("Enter estimated annual interest rate (%%): ");
    scanf("%lf", &rate);
    rate = rate * 0.01;
    printf("Enter target balance ($): ");
    scanf("%lf", &target);

    year = 0;
    interest = 0;

    printf("Year      Deposit      Interest       Balance\n");
    printf("----    ---------    ----------    ----------\n");

    static const char fmt_str[] = "%4d   %10.2lf    %10.2lf    %10.2lf\n";
    printf(fmt_str, year, balance, interest, balance);

    // we haven't checked if target was reached with the initial deposit so use
    // while instead of do...while
    while (balance < target)
    {
        year += 1;
        interest = (balance + deposit) * rate;
        balance = balance + deposit + interest;
        printf(fmt_str, year, balance, interest, balance);
    }

    printf("In year %3d, balance %.2lf reaches target %.2lf\n", year, balance, target);
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Enter starting balance ($): 250000.0
Enter amount deposited every year ($): 20000.0
Enter estimated annual interest rate (%): 10.0
Enter target balance ($): 2000000.0
Year      Deposit      Interest       Balance
----    ---------    ----------    ----------
   0    250000.00          0.00     250000.00
   1    297000.00      27000.00     297000.00
   2    348700.00      31700.00     348700.00
   3    405570.00      36870.00     405570.00
   4    468127.00      42557.00     468127.00
   5    536939.70      48812.70     536939.70
   6    612633.67      55693.97     612633.67
   7    695897.04      63263.37     695897.04
   8    787486.74      71589.70     787486.74
   9    888235.41      80748.67     888235.41
  10    999058.96      90823.54     999058.96
  11   1120964.85     101905.90    1120964.85
  12   1255061.34     114096.49    1255061.34
  13   1402567.47     127506.13    1402567.47
  14   1564824.22     142256.75    1564824.22
  15   1743306.64     158482.42    1743306.64
  16   1939637.30     176330.66    1939637.30
  17   2155601.03     195963.73    2155601.03
In year  17, balance 2155601.03 reaches target 2000000.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much, And now I understand it all. I'm only in week 7 so im brand new to this. Thank you.

Comment: @CSCIstudent No problem. You can accept (checkmark button) and upvote helpful answers (arrow buttons) on this site. Good luck with class!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in the logic, simply try with following hard coded values and solution works completely fine.. (Working example from [here](https://ideone.com/RMPDwv))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TARGET_VALUE 2000000
#define RATE .10

int main(void) 
{

int year;
double balance, target, finalbalance, deposit, rate, interest;


// Simply test for logic 
balance = 250000.0;
deposit= 20000.0;
interest= 10.0;
target = 2000000.0;

/*
printf("Enter starting balance ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &balance);
printf("Enter amount deposited every year ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &deposit);
printf("Enter estimated annual interest rate (\%%): ");
scanf("%lf", &rate);
printf("Enter target balance ($): ");
scanf("%lf", &target);
*/

year = 0;
interest = 0;

finalbalance = balance + deposit + interest;

printf("\nYear    Deposit    Interest    Balance");
printf("\n----    -------    --------    -------");
printf("\n%d   %.2lf    %.2lf    %.2lf", year, deposit, interest,
      finalbalance);
do {
    finalbalance = finalbalance + deposit + interest;
    year += 1;
    interest = (finalbalance + deposit) * RATE;
    printf("\n%d    %.2lf    %.2lf    %.2lf", year, deposit, interest,finalbalance);
} while (finalbalance <= target);

printf("\nIn year %d, balance %.2lf reaches target %.2lf", year, balance, target);
return 0;

}
```

Output :

```
Year    Deposit    Interest    Balance
----    -------    --------    -------
0   20000.00    0.00    270000.00
0    20000.00    0.00    290000.00
1    20000.00    31000.00    341000.00
2    20000.00    36100.00    397100.00
3    20000.00    41710.00    458810.00
4    20000.00    47881.00    526691.00
5    20000.00    54669.10    601360.10
6    20000.00    62136.01    683496.11
7    20000.00    70349.61    773845.72
8    20000.00    79384.57    873230.29
9    20000.00    89323.03    982553.32
10    20000.00    100255.33    1102808.65
11    20000.00    112280.87    1235089.52
12    20000.00    125508.95    1380598.47
13    20000.00    140059.85    1540658.32
14    20000.00    156065.83    1716724.15
15    20000.00    173672.42    1910396.57
16    20000.00    193039.66    2123436.22
In year 17, balance 250000.00 reaches target 2000000.00
```